# Converting live MyISAM table to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, myisam, mysqldump

I have a table that tracks web traffic. The table is constantly written and read from. Since table is pretty big in size I have to make sure the application will not "freeze" in the process of converting the table's storage engine from **MyISAM -> InnoDB**. Below is what I'm planning to do based on information I could gather from other posts. Please tell me if I'm missing anything.

1. `mysqldump -u -p --lock-tables=false mydb tracking > tracking.sql` - from what I understand this should not lock "tracking" table
2. Rename table name in the sql file to tracking_new
3. `mysql -u -p mydb < tracking.sql`
4. `ALTER TABLE mydb.tracking_new ENGINE=InnoDB;`
5. Insert new rows to "tracking_new" table that were written to the original table while performing dump

   ```
   SELECT @last_id := tracking.id FROM mydb.tracking_new ORDER BY tracking.id DESC LIMIT 1;    
   INSERT INTO mydb.tracking_new
   SELECT * FROM mydb.tracking WHERE tracking.id > @last_id;
   ```

Rename tables

```
RENAME TABLE 
    mydb.tracking TO mydb.tracking_old, 
    mydb.tracking_new TO mydb.tracking;
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't have any triggers on that table, the simplest way to do this without locking the table is to use [`pt-online-schema-change`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html).

Make sure you have enough extra disk space to accommodate this change. The table will be larger when you convert it to InnoDB, and you need to maintain both copies of the table during the conversion. For example, if your table is 100 GB make sure you have at least 200+ GB of free disk space.

You should test this out in a non-production environment first to make sure it works for you and to find out exactly how much disk space you need.

The syntax for your case is quite simple.

First do a dry run to verify that it will work:

```
pt-online-schema-change --alter "ENGINE=InnoDB" D=mydb,t=tracking --dry-run
```

Then execute it:

```
pt-online-schema-change --alter "ENGINE=InnoDB" D=mydb,t=tracking --execute
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading your MyISAM table and ALTER it after, change the MySQL engine directly in your SQL dump file (on table definition) :

The table will be restored directly in **InnoDB** engine :

MyISAM

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `t` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

InnoDB

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `t` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The step 5 seems to be good.

Best,

Max.

Comment: Isn't --single-transaction only for InnoDB?

Comment: My bad, you're right, I answared to quickly, MyISAM does not support transactions so this option has no impact on MyISAM tables... Sorry again

Answer (score 0):

If the tracking table is MyISAM, you would probably have to rely on [**concurrent_insert**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_concurrent_insert). What that does is let the tracking table add new rows without locking for hole in the middle of the MyISAM table. It would just do a quick-and-dirty appending of all incoming rows.

If you set [**concurrent_insert**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_concurrent_insert) to 2, you should be able to write to the tracking table and still copy data.

Here is an alternate suggestion:

**STEP 01 : Activate concurrent_size to always append**

```
mysql -Dmydb -ANe"SET GLOBAL concurrent_insert = 2"
```

**STEP 02 : Create InnoDB version of the table**

```
SQL="CREATE TABLE tracking_innodb LIKE tracking;"
SQL="${SQL} ALTER TABLE tracking_innodb ENGINE=InnoDB;"
mysql -Dmydb -ANe"${SQL}"
```

**STEP 03 : Perform copy of tracking table directly into the new table**

```
mysqldump --no-create-info mydb tracking | sed 's/tracking/tracking_innodb' | mysql -Dmydb
```

**STEP 04 : Rename tracking table to prevent new inserts**

```
mysql -Dmydb -ANe"ALTER TABLE tracking RENAME tracking_old"
```

**STEP 05 : Retrieve Last ID in tracking_old**

```
SQL="SELECT id FROM tracking_new ORDER BY tracking.id DESC LIMIT 1"
LASTID=`mysql -Dmydb -ANe"`
```

**STEP 06 : Retrieve remaining data**

```
SQL="INSERT INTO tracking_new SELECT * FROM tracking_odl WHERE id > ${LASTID}"
mysql -Dmydb -ANe"${SQL}"
```

**STEP 07 : Rename tracking_new to tracking**

```
mysql -Dmydb -ANe"ALTER TABLE tracking_new RENAME tracking"
```

## CAVEAT

Your original proposal is actually just as good. Most of my answer looks like your anyway. The only difference is that I introduce an outage to guarantee no new inserts starting at `STEP 04`. An outage comes a little earlier in your plan (`STEP 02`).

I added concurrent_insert to speed up inserts into the MyISAM table duing the mysqldump.

You can either go with your plan or mine. Just add `concurrent_insert=2` to the mix.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I thought --lock-tables=false will let inserts to happen during dump?

Comment: That will tell mysqldump not to issue a formal `LOCK TABLES` command on the table. Setting `concurrent_insert=2` is for relaxing the MyISAM storage engine so that it does not check for holes (or gaps) in the table before performing the INSERT of a row. In reality, if you have never issued a DELETE against the tracking table, then `concurrent_insert=2` is not needed.