# Timeout on ALTER TABLE table ENGINE=InnoDB - is table still converted?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, myisam

I'm converting tables in an old MYISAM database to InnoDB to increase robustness in case of power loss etc.

I'm using Mysql 5.5.x

Before doing the production system, I am doing a trial run on a copy of the DB on a test machine - just in case.

I backed up the tables with mysqldump [using this information.](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-backup-and-restore-export-and-import-mysql-databases-tutorial/)

Some tables take more than the timeout (600sec) to convert, and so I get an error 2013:

```
ALTER TABLE voice.members ENGINE=InnoDB Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

When I check the table later, it's listed as InnoDB.

```
show table status in voice like "members";
```

Here are my questions:

1. Can I assume that the conversion went as intended?
2. Are there any obvious checks I should perform to ensure that integrity is not compromized?
3. Should I enforce that the DB is single user before conversion, or is my only worry that response time might be bad while conversion is ongoing + loss of work in case of a restore from the initial backup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## QUESTION #1

> Can I assume that the conversion went as intended?

Never assume a conversion until you test it. Thank you for backing it up in advance.

## QUESTION #2

> Are there any obvious checks I should perform to ensure that integrity is not compromised?

For any given table `mydb.mytable` you converted to InnoDB, please check two things

#### TABLE COUNT

Take a count of all the rows

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mydb.mytable;
```

Run the same count on the MyISAM backup.

#### CHECKSUM

Run a checksum of the whole table

```
CHECKSUM TABLE mydb.mytable;
```

Run the same checksum on the MyISAM backup.

#### SUMMARY ON QUESTION #2

You should get the same count and checksum values for both the InnoDB and MyISAM tables.

#### SUGGESTION FOR QUESTION #2

If you would like to manage the InnoDB conversion in stages, try doing this next time

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable_new LIKE mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_new ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO mydb.mytable_new SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable RENAME mydb.mytable_old;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_new RENAME mydb.mytable;
```

Use the table, test it in staging, kick the tires.

If you are satisfied the table is fine, drop the old table

```
DROP TABLE mydb.mytable_old;
```

or retain it as a backup

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_old RENAME mydb.mytable_myisam;
```

## QUESTION #3

> Should I enforce that the DB is single user before conversion, or is my only worry that response time might be bad while conversion is ongoing + loss of work in case of a restore from the initial backup?

If you want convert a live MyISAM table to InnoDB, see my post [Converting live MyISAM table to InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/converting-live-myisam-table-to-innodb/53645#53645)

If you are very skeptical or fearful of data loss, your idea of single user access is fine.

You could just restart mysql like this

```
service mysql restart --skip-networking
```

Login to mysql as `root@localhost`. Do the conversion, then

```
service mysql restart
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!